# Place text label into corresponding slice of pie chart using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe below and I create apie chart using ggplot2 but the text labels are not inside the correct slice and some of them overlap one the other. I need also text not to overlap one another.

```
HU2<-c(1,  2,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11)
Freq<-c(5118, 2226, 5817,  159, 6766,   27,  984,  654,   89)
Abs_Freq<-c("0.23", "0.10", "0.27", "0.01", "0.31", "0.00", "0.05", "0.03", "0.00")
df$label <- scales::percent(as.numeric(df$Abs_Freq))

p2<-ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_bar(aes(x="", y=as.numeric(Abs_Freq), fill=HU2), stat="identity", width = 1)+
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  theme_void()+
  geom_text(aes(x=1, y = cumsum(as.numeric(Abs_Freq)) - as.numeric(Abs_Freq)/2, label=label))
p2
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ggplot2 coord\_polar preserve order when using fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41717159/ggplot2-coord-polar-preserve-order-when-using-fill)

Answer (score 1):

It's often easiest to diagnose pie-chart problems in cartesian space before using polar coordinates. In this case, instead of calculating the cumalitive frequency manually, you can use `position = position_stack()` to place the text in the right wedge. Note that also the `group` aesthetic in the text and in the bar should be identical if you want to have the stacking work as intended.

```r
library(ggplot2)

HU2<-c(1,  2,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11)
Freq<-c(5118, 2226, 5817,  159, 6766,   27,  984,  654,   89)
Abs_Freq<-c("0.23", "0.10", "0.27", "0.01", "0.31", "0.00", "0.05", "0.03", "0.00")
df <- data.frame(
  HU2 = HU2,
  Freq = Freq,
  Abs_Freq = Abs_Freq
)

df$label <- scales::percent(as.numeric(df$Abs_Freq))

ggplot(data=df)+
  geom_col(aes(x="", y=as.numeric(Abs_Freq), fill=as.factor(HU2)),
           width = 1)+
  coord_polar("y", start=0)+
  theme_void()+
  geom_text(aes(x=1, y = as.numeric(Abs_Freq), label=label, group = as.factor(HU2)),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>